# Integral inequality in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I came across this problem :

Let $f\colon [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a continuous vector valued function. Then it is true that:

$$\left\Vert\int \limits_a ^b f(t) dt\right\Vert \leq \int \limits_a^b \left\Vert f(t)\right\Vert dt$$

I consider that the integral of $f$ is given by integrating each component and then I am trying to reduce it to having an integral inequality for $n$ single valued functions but I am stuck.

I would appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$. Then, we know that
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\left(\int_a^b f_1(x)\,dx,\ldots,\int_a^b f_n(x)\,dx\right)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \big(\,f_1(t_{N,i}),\ldots,f_n(t_{N,i})\big),
$$
where $t_{N,i}=a+i\frac{b-a}{N}$.

Clearly
$$
\Big\|\sum_{i=1}^N \big(\,f_1(t_{N,i}),\ldots,f_n(t_{N,i})\big)\Big\|\le
\sum_{i=1}^N \big\|\big(\,f_1(t_{N,i}),\ldots,f_n(t_{N,i})\big)\big\|,
$$
and hence
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{N}\Big\|\sum_{i=1}^N \big(\,f_1(t_{N,i}),\ldots,f_n(t_{N,i})\big)\Big\|\le
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N 
\big\|\big(\,f_1(t_{N,i}),\ldots,f_n(t_{N,i})\big)\big\|,
$$
The left hand side of the above tends to $\left\|\int_a^n f(x)\,dx\,\right\|$ while the right hand side tends to  $\int_a^n \|f(x)\|\,dx.$